# x64 inline assembly in c to align instructions

Tags: c, gcc, alignment, x86-64, inline-assembly

I've got a very hot instruction loop which needs to be properly aligned on 32-bytes boundaries to maximize [Intel's Instruction Fetcher](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6355/intels-haswell-architecture/6) effectiveness.

This issue is specific to Intel not-too-old line of CPU (from Sandy Bridge onward). Failure to align properly the beginning of the loop results in up to 20 % speed loss, which is definitely too noticeable.
This issue is pretty rare, one needs a highly optimized set of instructions for the instruction fetcher to become the bottleneck. But fortunately, it's not a unique case. Here is a [nice article explaining in details](http://pzemtsov.github.io/2014/05/12/mystery-of-unstable-performance.html) how such a problem can be detected.

The problem is, gcc nor clang would care aligning properly this instruction loop. It makes compiling this code a nightmare producing random outcome, depending on how "good" the hot loop is aligned by chance. It also means that modifying a totally unrelated function can nonetheless highly impact performance of the hot loop.

Already tried several compiler flags, none of them gives satisfying result.

*[Edit]* More detailed description of tried compilation flags :

- `-falign-functions=32` : no impact or negative impact
- `-falign-jumps=32` : no impact
- `-falign-loops=32` : works fine when the hot loop is isolated into a tiny piece of test code. But in normal build, the compilation flag is applied across the entire source, and in this case it is detrimental : aligning *all* loops on 32-bytes is bad for performance. Only the very hot ones benefit from it.
- Also attempted to use `__attribute__((optimize("align-loops=32")))` in the function declaration. Doesn't produce any effect (identical binary generated, as if the the statement wasn't there). Later confirmed by `gcc` support team to be effectively ignored. *Edit* : @Jester indicates in comment that the statement works with gcc 5+. Unfortunately, my dev station uses primarily gcc 4.8.4, and this is more a problem of portability, since I don't control the final compiler used in the build process.

Only building using PGO can reliably produce expected performance, but PGO cannot be accepted as a solution since this piece of code will be integrated into other programs using their own build chain.

So, I'm considering inline assembly.
This would be specific to x64 instruction set, so no portability required.

If my understanding is correct, assembly like NASM allows the use of statements such as : `ALIGN 32` which would force the next instruction to be aligned on 32 bytes boundaries.

Since the target source code is in C, it would be necessary to include this statement. For example, something like `asm("ALIGN 32");`
(which of course doesn't work).

I hope it's mostly a matter of knowing the right instruction to write, and not something deeper such as "it's impossible".

Comment: _Already tried several compiler flags, none of them gives satisfying result._ ... should have listed those. As FUZxxl wrote, `-falign-loops` is specifically for this purpose, so have you tried that?

Comment: yes, already tried `-falign-loops`. It works fine if the code _only_ contains the specific loop. But the flag is applied across the whole source, and applying this conditions to all loops is on average worse for performance.

Comment: See, that's why I said you can apply that to the particular function using an attribute. Inline asm is not the right solution ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I also tried to use `__attribute__`. And this one doesn't work at all. No impact on generated binary, and it was confirmed to be effectively ignored by `gcc` support.

Comment: @Cyan Which attributes did you try? Changing compiler options in a source file is generally finicky. Please consider telling us what you tried so we don't ask you all of the things you have already tried before. You also didn't tell us that you tried `-falign-loops` and that it works and that it is inacceptable on the whole program. Why did you leave that out? Especially since it solves your problem (almost). What about just compiling the affected source code forms with `-falign-loops` and leaving the others without that option?

Comment: I once described extensively all the things I tried, and as a result, was downvoted, on the ground that I had already tried everything possible, so should not dare to expect something else could exist.
This gave me a bad experience ...

Comment: Edited the question to add a few more elements already tested before attempting the `__asm__` route ...

Comment: @Cyan Your post isn't downvoted. I'm sorry if you had a bad experience, but writing an answer that turns out to be something you already tried in an unsatisfactory way is frustrating for me. If you tried “several compiler flags,” it is always helpful to write why the flags where not helpful so we can understand the limitations. Thank you for amending the question with details.

Comment: @Cyan: that downvoting of your other question sounds odd.  Can you post a link?

Comment: @Cyan Is it possible in your scenario to only compile that one translation unit with `-falign-loops=32`? If you have a makefile, it's easy to add a special rule for the important file.

Comment: I tried it too.
It did not worked (same performance as no-flag).
Not sure why, I presumed `-falign-loop` could be a linking-stage compilation flag.

Comment: If you're using link-time optimization `-flto`, then yeah, probably not all the options used with `-c` will matter.

Comment: ah sorry, no, I'm not using `-flto`. It's too new unfortunately, so not guaranteed to be present. This is the regular `.c` -> `.o` -> link process.

Which basically makes me now wonder why it did not worked ... 
Is function alignment decided into the `.o`, or can it be changed later on by the final linking stage ?

Comment: Just tested, you need gcc 5.x for the attribute to work.

Comment: Nice to know @Jester !
Indeed, I'm mostly using gcc 4.8.4 on my dev station.
I've got a secondary dev station using 5.2.1, but it's only used for confirmation and benchmark.

Comment: @Cyan Loop alignment is generated in the assembly and part of the object file. It's a compile-stage optimization, not a link-stage optimization. Supplying the option at link time (or not supplying it) should not make a difference.

Comment: Did you check the generated assembly (`gcc -S`) to see how the loop is currently aligned?

Comment: @Cyan: thanks for taking the time to edit your question after accepting an answer.  It's a much more useful post now: I'd upvote it again if I could for the edit.  Your accepted solution also relies on a GNU C extension (`asm`).  There's a minor risk of the `.align` ending up somewhere unfortunate after compiler loop transformations and so on, so you might consider always having the `__attribute__` (since it's a harmless no-op on old compilers), and maybe even `#ifdef` the .align.  e.g. `#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ < 5`

Comment: Also, gcc5 has many significant improvements, and makes less clunky code in many cases.  I often look at asm output on http://gcc.godbolt.org/, and I think I remember even gcc 4.9 making better code than gcc 4.8.  Often I only look at the latest gcc and clang versions, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Sure, the asm statement will be encapsulated into macro `#ifdef`, since it needs to be present on x64 target only, and indeed, the precise asm statement vary depending on compiler.

Comment: The issue with hot loop instruction alignment exists also on gcc 5.2.

I could test and confirm that `__attribute__` works well on gcc 5.2.
It improves speed measurably. For some reason though, the `asm` version provides a bit faster speed. Maybe because `__attribute__` works at function level while `asm` can be more precise, at loop level (?).

Another plus for `asm` is that it does not depend on gcc version > 5, and can even work on non-gcc compilers (provided the right syntax can be encapsulated into macros).

Comment: @Cyan: Probably aligning all loops in the function did worse than just aligning that one loop.  32B boundaries force the end of a uop cache line, which for loops is what really matters.  It's not directly and instruction-fetch issue.  See http://agner.org/optimize/ (esp. the microarch doc).  Small loops (28 uops) fit in the loop buffer, and in theory shouldn't need alignment.  Extra padding where it's not needed certainly can hurt.  Esp. when the CPU actually has to run the `nop`s, and not just jump over them (like the padding to align the start of a function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similarly to NASM, the GNU assembler supports the `.align`  pseudo OP for alignment:

```
volatile asm (".align 32");
```

For a non-assembly solution, you could try to supply `-falign-loops=32` and possibly `-falign-functions=32`, `-falign-jumps=32` as needed.

Comment: And then hope that the next instruction is going to be the loop already. As far as I understand, OP has that in C.

Comment: Does not look that will add the required nops or branches to the code. So maybe a branch should preceed it.

Comment: @Olaf The GNU assembler inserts nops for alignment in executable sections by default. It even tries to insert more efficient long nops where possible.

Comment: Also note you can add the particular optimization settings via function attributes, in case you don't want to compile the whole file with them.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Nice! That's why tools which are use by the programmers themselves are preferable:-)

Comment: @Olaf gcc is not all sunshine'n'rainbows though, some parts really suck (like them being adamant about the sucking behaviour of `__attribute__((unused))`).

Comment: Definitely the right answer.
Note that I've tried `-falign*` already, but they do not work well, being applied across the whole source, instead of a specific position.

Also tried `__attribute__` but this one doesn't work at all.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I talked about gas. And I very well know about the nastynesses. But there is never sunshine without rain, and they are definitively the lesser evil compared to most commercial tools (especially taking into account prices >>1000€ for some of them). Not sure what your problem is with the `unused` attribute.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, I meant `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` which because of an asine decision 20 years ago cannot be silenced by casting the result of the function to `void` as is the generally accepted convention since 40 years ago.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I think it is well disputable to ignore a result the designer of that function thinks should never be ignored. Egal!

Comment: @Olaf Something something “death of the author” something something.

Comment: Thank you :)__asm volatile  (".align 32");