# Could you use C inline assembly to align instructions? (without Compiler optimizations)

Tags: c, caching, optimization, alignment, inline-assembly

I have to do a university project where we have to use cache optimizations to improve the performance of a given code but **we must not use compiler optimizations** to achieve it.

One of the ideas I had reading the bibliography is to align the beginning of a basic block to a line cache size. But can you do something like:

```
asm(".align 64;")
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
... (whole basic block)
```

in order to achieve what I'm looking for? I have no idea if it's possible to do that in terms of instruction alignment. I've seen some trick like `_mm_malloc` to achieve data alignment but none for instructions. Could anyone please give me some light on the matter?

Comment: Aligning instructions is not likely to do much to improve performance until you have so much code executed repetitively that critical parts of it are frequently evicted from cache. A class assignment to improve the performance of a program by way of cache optimizations is more likely to be focused on data use than on code layout.

Comment: @EricPostpischil understood. Nevertheless, could you please confirm if (when it's worth the case) the align of instructions can be done like in my example?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439641/x64-inline-assembly-in-c-to-align-instructions . Note that you could also allocate some memory space to put assembled binary instruction in it manually and play with mmap so you can execute it (by default, processes cannot execute data allocated with functions like malloc for sake of security). This is what just in time compilers do though it is a bit tricky to do.

Comment: @S.Buzzoni: It is not reliable. Generally, an `asm` construct does not tell the compiler to put its contents anywhere particular, just somewhere in the sequence of instructions generated for the flow of code it is part of.

Comment: If you can use inline asm but must compile with anti-optimized debug mode, there are likely major speedups from rewriting the whole thing in inline asm.  See also [C loop optimization help for final assignment (with compiler optimization disabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32000917) re: how silly it is to optimize source code for debug mode, but also some things you can do.  You definitely want to use `register int i` to let a debug build keep it in a register.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ended up spending more hours than I care to admit writing an answer; turns out this does seem to fully work "well" in front of `do{}while` loops, at least simple ones, with GCC with optimization disabled of course.  I didn't test with nested loops or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL:DR: This might not be very useful (since modern x86 with a uop cache often doesn't care about code alignment<sup>1</sup>), but does "work" in front of a `do{}while()` loop**, which can [compile directly to asm with the same layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump), without any loop setup (prologue) instructions before the actual top of the loop.  (The target of the backwards branch).

In general, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm and especially never use GNU C Basic `asm("foo");` inside a function, but in debug mode (the `-O0` default, aka optimizations disabled) each statement (including `asm();`) compiles to a separate block of asm in source order.  So you case doesn't actually need Extended `asm(".p2align 4" ::: "memory")` to order the asm statement wrt. memory operations.  (Also in recent GCC, a memory clobber is implicit for Basic asm with a non-empty template string).  At worst with optimization enabled the padding could go somewhere useless and hurt performance, but not correctness, unlike most uses of `asm()`.

---

#### How this actually compiles

This does not exactly work; a **C `for` loop compiles to some asm instructions *before* the asm loop**.  Especially when using a `for(a;b;c)` loop with some before-first-iteration initialization in statement `a`!  You can of course pull that out in the source, but GCC's `-O0` strategy for [compiling `while` and `for` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump) is to enter the loop with a `jmp` to the condition at the bottom.

But that `jmp` alone is only one small (2-byte) instruction, so **aligning before that would put the top of the loop *near* the start of a possible instruction fetch block**, which still gets most of the benefit if that was ever a bottleneck.  (Or near the start of a new group of uop-cache lines Sandybridge-family x86 where 32-byte boundaries are relevant.  Or even a 64-byte I-cache line, although that's rarely relevant and could result in a lot of NOPs executed to reach that boundary.  And bloated code size.)

```
void foo(register int *p)
{
    // always use .p2align n or .balign 1<<n so it's unambiguous across targets like MacOS vs. Linux, never .align
    asm("   .p2align 5 # from inline asm");
    for (register int *endp = p + 102400; p<endp ; p++) {
        *p += 123;
    }
}
```

Compiles as follows on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyagA%2BudTkVjVEQJDqzTAGF09AK5smBpwBkCTNgAcp4ARtikIABMAOzkAA7oSsT2TK4eXgaJyXZC/oEhbOGRsVbYNrlMIkQspETpnt48ZRWp1bVE%2BcFhEdHNSjV1DZn9g50B3UW9UTwAlFbo7qSonFwAbugEmADUgugQpNjABAMR2wFE2wBU8bMApFoAgncxAEIPj9tf2yxKbBB3KJRb4AOniUQkBGATG2AFZtoCAMy7UjoNjnJj0CY/P6AqL3RHvJ7fXZkbYHI4nIhnC7XJzxBGIgAi2wZgNe2x4Wii0i0WjuhNZAuc9MZHPi7PZswRbw%2BJJJNwRUXezM5UURAqJn2%2BLyZH11H1%2B/zxd1hziYpvNlotQIJWo2W22oVqFOOp1IGMuN3uTxeWpJhzd1I9tKuooFLLZys53N5/MJcu%2BRoBQNB4Mh0LhSuRNFR6ICWMCOLYeLtia%2Bgg9EDFrMZzm24cFEuVUpl/vlX0VktVPHVmvLMr1vpiQ%2BeT2TJrNFqn1tL/aeDp2zoAXq6qTThNdbvrZcTvoH1yHN2GmJg2aqoxyuTy%2BfPtV8J6mvmCIVjM/CkSi0RjC9hi3OEz3L5MHQNsBwVS8IzVDVAPveVm3eFtYJJXUAHckAYbAIHPet6TLYdR31dUCBobZ%2BXHP4UyiWcZxnW070XBs2HiIgAE96HQdB4gge5dzgytyQPd1PXORkWS5PlJMkmsAFoZIIMVePbL4DQIojEScEiuHmehuFhfhvC4HRyHQbh6yURZlj/JE%2BHIIhtG0%2BYAGsQGkABOEFETcmJYT5RFEV7REYhiAA2WFDG4aR%2BDYEAYiiEFpB4EKAA43N7ZLpGSnhYWS8hDOM0yuH4JQQC0OyHPmOBYBQRYiHidwiEoRxCBIUgtgMQRhDECROBkORhGUNRNCMvQDFQ0gWHibg%2BB0vSDIckzuAAeQa%2BrLnQUj1GSkKZJC6RtmAVBUE5HhPPJVxmMwj0bNmfh7JG2Z5iQbAWBwSIeIirgovIGLYhBHKAq0ZKYmyngMp4Ny8oWwritK8qHuckBES0EEgf8kK0tSqIsq0cLdK4RF5pGxaivhnRKsQCAUAwS7GAoKgIBp%2BIrrQYAeB4REBAYYMSogUIFtCAJalY6b%2BBpjhhCWzEReJnA2GMYBJFlghDlsAg1mwEreH4bB1GwVAGtWWyLnKBasVCCbSFY1wcAWog2pi7X5hoIxgCUAA1AhsFQpb4mYUX%2BtEcRJD6zrFBUDQFv0ZojBMEBzFMSxzZKyB5i4yotZkpatG2GTgBzmSaCYdAZN%2BVimFQJBUWL9wlBk9wmFQgJMBkmpQkYJRc4AdQkehivKfXKkcU9hiacg/AmQpiiyJIUiEUeZ5yVIuin3p%2BgHtWhHaIY3EaAxrEHtoxhXnpIlGDoF/PuoT6mM/5gspYVgMe3sCN7TPv0qHicKradr2g6jonTOhAZw5Btj4GIGSGyYCLrMzptmOYd0KqI0RNIEEUQQqhVhNILyYMeAxDcnjSK0UpB8i/gVbgsMyr3XJuQKqyA0BojgREJqjMmEs1QGzDmXN6A82oPzYmgtWBWwWuLZgRApb0BlsZOWCslYyJVofDWWtbK631obAOJt8bGXNpba2WBVjGXtgQR2M0BCuw9l7H2ftDK2TDt1EOsgw6DUjsTfQURDAK3jhYQwBBQgpw%2BunVImds65yLiXMuFcq5CEWHXBuTdTytxYO3TW3de65wGJgCM0J3BuTcv3VoDgIBOEvuPU8N9p7NGyHPNIu8RgJFnpUCpa8WiHy3mMUpB9N5VGPpPU%2B%2B8Ol1LHgMDozS74LEfr1Oyhw36zS4J/fK/Af7bV2vtQ6x12bANAeAlqUD1TNG2LAq62Z8RIIRuQFyiJYQgj2qlUKiVUpaC5NlT631FkkyoWTRyn0ohEwoaTGh3yNakGSA4aQQA).  Note that the way I used `register` meant I got not-terrible asm despite the debug build, and didn't have to combine `p++` into `p++ <= endp` or `*(p++) += 123;` to make store/reload overhead less bad (because there isn't any in the first place for `register` locals).  And I used a pointer increment / compare to keep the asm simple, and harder for debug mode to deoptimize into more wasted asm instructions.

```
# GCC11.3 -O0 (the default with no options, except for -masm=intel added by Godbolt)
foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx                        # GCC stupidly picks a call-preserved reg it has to save
        mov     rax, rdi
           .p2align 5 # from inline asm
        lea     rbx, [rax+409600]          # endp = p+102400
        jmp     .L2                        # jump to the p<endp condition before the first iteration
## The actual top of the loop.  9 bytes past the alignment boundary
.L3:                                       # do{
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        add     edx, 123
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx         # A memory destination add dword [rax], 123  would be 2 uops for the front-end (fused-domain) on Intel, vs. 3 for 3 separate instructions.
        add     rax, 4                       # p++
.L2:
        cmp     rax, rbx
        jb      .L3                        # }while(p<endp)
        nop
        nop                                # These aren't for alignment, IDK what this is for.
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]     # restore RBX
        leave                              # and restore RBP / tear down stack frame
        ret
```

This loop is 5 uops long (assuming macro-fusion of cmp/JCC), so can run at 1 cycle per iteration on Ice Lake or Zen, if all goes well.  (Load / store of 1 dword per cycle is not much memory bandwidth, so that should keep up over a large array, maybe even if it doesn't fit in L3 cahce.)  Or on Haswell for example, maybe 1.25 cycles per iteration, or [maybe a little worse due to loop-buffer effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311872/is-performance-reduced-when-executing-loops-whose-uop-count-is-not-a-multiple-of).

If you use "binary" output mode on Godbolt, you can see that `lea rbx, [rax+409600]` is a 7-byte instruction, while `jmp  .L2` is 2 bytes, and that the address of the top of the loop is `0x401149`, i.e. 9 bytes into the 16-byte fetch-block, on CPUs that fetch in that size.  I aligned by 32, so it's only wasted 2 uops out of the first uop cache line associated with this block, so we're still relatively good in term of 32-byte blocks.

(Godbolt "binary" mode compiles and links into an executable, and runs `objdump -d` on that.  That also lets us see the `.p2align` directive expanded into a NOP instruction of some width, or more than one if it had to skip more than 11 bytes, the default max NOP width for GAS for x86-64.  Remember these NOP instructions have to get fetched and go through the pipeline every time control passes over this asm statement, so huge alignment inside a function is a bad thing for that as well as for I-cache footprint.)

**A fairly obvious transformation gets the LEA before the `.p2align`.** (See the asm in the Godbolt link for all of these source versions if you're curious).

```
    register int *endp = p + 102400;
    asm("   .p2align 5 # from inline asm");
    for ( ; p < endp ; p++) {
        *p += 123;
    }
```

Or `while (p < endp){... ; p++}` also does the trick.  The top of the asm loop becomes the following, with only a 2-byte `jmp` to the loop condition.  So this is pretty decent, and gets most of the benefit.

```
        lea     rbx, [rax+409600]
           .p2align 5 # from inline asm
        jmp     .L5                       # 2-byte instruction
.L6:
```

It might be possible to achieve the same thing with `for(foo=bar, asm(".p2align 4) ; p<endp ; p++)`.  But if you're declaring a variable in the first part of a `for` statement, the comma operator won't work to let you sneak in a separate statement.

##### To actually align the asm loop, we can write it as a `do{}while`.

```
    register int *endp = p + 102400;
    asm("   .p2align 5 # from inline asm");
    do {
        *p += 123;
        p++;
    }while(p < endp);
```

```
        lea     rbx, [rax+409600]
           .p2align 5 # from inline asm
.L8:                                     # do{
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        add     edx, 123
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        add     rax, 4
        cmp     rax, rbx
        jb      .L8                      # while(p<endp)
```

No `jmp` at the start, no branch-target label inside the loop.  (Which is interesting if you wanted to try `-falign-labels=32` to get GCC to pad for you without having it put NOPs *inside* the loop.  See below: -falign-loops doesn't work at `-O0`.)

Since I'm hard-coding a non-zero size, no `p == endp` check runs before the first iteration.  If that length was a runtime variable, e.g. a function arg, you could do `if(n==0) return;` before the loop.  Or more generally, put the loop *inside* an `if` like GCC does when compiling a `for` or `while` loop with optimization enabled, if it can't prove that it always runs at least one iteration.

```
  if(n!=0) {
      register int *endp = p + n;
      asm (".p2align 4");
      do {
          ...
      }while(p!=endp); 
  }
```

#### Getting GCC to do this for you: `-falign-loops=16` doesn't work at `-O0`

GCC `-O2` enables `-falign-loops=16:11:8` or something like that (align by 16 if that would skip fewer than 11 bytes, otherwise align by 8).  That's why GCC uses a sequence of two `.p2align` directives, with a padding limit on the first one ([see the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/P2align.html#P2align)).

```
        .p2align 4,,10            # what GCC does on its own
        .p2align 3
```

**But using `-falign-loops=16` does nothing at `-O0`.  It seems GCC -O0 doesn't know what a loop is.** :P

However, GCC *does* respect `-falign-labels` even at `-O0`.  But unfortunately that applies to **all** labels, including the loop entry point inside the inner loop.  [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EWsqee5b7).

```
# gcc -O0 -falign-labels=16
## from compiling endp=...; asm(); while() {}
        lea     rbx, [rax+409600]              # endp = ...
           .p2align 5 # from inline asm
        jmp     .L5
        .p2align 4                         # from GCC itself, pads another 14 bytes to an odd multiple of 16 (if you didn't remove the manual .p2align 5)
.L6:
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        add     edx, 123
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        add     rax, 4
        .p2align 4                         # from GCC itself: one 5-byte NOP in this particular case
.L5:
        cmp     rax, rbx
        jb      .L6
```

Putting a NOP inside the inner-most loop is worse than misaligning its start on modern x86 CPUs.

You don't have this problem with a `do{}while()` loop, but in that case it also seems to work to use `asm()` to put an alignment directive there.

(I used [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for the compile options to minimize clutter without filtering out directives, which would include `.p2align`.  If I just wanted to see where the inline asm went, I could have used `asm("nop #hi mom")` to make it visible with directives filtered out.)

---

If you can use inline asm but must compile with anti-optimized debug mode, there are likely major speedups from rewriting the whole inner loop in inline asm, with input/output constraints.  ([But don't really do that; it's hard to get right](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) and in real life a normal person would just enable optimizations as a first step.)

---

#### Footnote 1: code alignment doesn't help much on modern x86, may help some on others

This is unlikely to be helpful even if you do actually align the target of the backwards branch (rather than just some loop prologue); modern x86 CPUs with uop caches (Sandybridge-family and Zen-family) and loop buffers (Nehalem and later for Intel) don't care very much about loop alignment.

**It could help more on an older x86 CPU, or maybe for some other ISAs; only x86 is so hard to decode that uop caches are a thing**  (You didn't actually specify x86, but currently most people are using x86 CPUs in their desktops/laptops so I'm assuming that.)

**The main reason alignment of branch targets helps (especially tops of loops)**, is when the CPU fetches a 16-byte-aligned block that *includes* the target address, most of the machine code in that block will be *after* it, and thus part of loop body that's about to run another iteration.  (Bytes before the branch target are wasted in that fetch cycle).

But the worst case of mis-alignment (barring other weird effects) just costs you 1 extra cycle of front-end fetch to get more instructions in the loop body. (e.g. if the top of the loop had an address ending with `0xf`, so it was the last byte of a 16-byte block, the aligned 16-byte block containing that byte would only contain that one useful byte at the end.)  That might be a one-byte instruction like `cdq`, but pipelines are often 4 instructions wide, or more.

(Or 3-wide in the early Intel P6-family days before there were buffers between fetch, pre-decode (length finding) and decode.  Buffering can hide bubbles if the rest of the loop decodes efficiently and the average instruction-length is short.  But decode was still a significant bottleneck until Nehalem's loop buffer could recycle the decode results (uops) for a small loop (a couple dozen uops).  And Sandybridge-family added a uop cache to cache large loops that include multiple functions that get called frequently. [David Kanter's deep-dive on SnB](https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/) has nice block diagrams, and see also https://www.agner.org/optimize/ especially Agner's microarch pdf.

Even then, it only helps at all when front-end (instruction fetch/decode) bandwidth is a problem, not some back-end bottleneck (actually executing those instructions).  Out-of-order exec usually does a pretty good job of letting the CPU run as fast as the slowest bottleneck, not waiting until after a cache-miss load to get later instructions fetched and decoded.  (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692718/how-many-cpu-cycles-are-needed-for-each-assembly-instruction/44980899#44980899), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca), and especially [Modern Microprocessors A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/).)

There are cases where it could help on a Skylake CPU where a microcode update disabled the loop buffer (LSD), so a tiny loop body split across a 32-byte boundary can run at best 1 iteration per 2 cycles (fetching uops from 2 separate cache lines).  Or on Skylake again, tweaking code alignment this way could help avoid the JCC erratum (that can make part of your code run from legacy decode instead of the uop cache) if you can't pass `-Wa,-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries` to get the assembler to work around it.  ([How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256646/how-can-i-mitigate-the-impact-of-the-intel-jcc-erratum-on-gcc)).  These problems are specific to Skylake-derived microarchitectures, and were fixed in Ice Lake.

Of course, anti-optimized debug-mode code is so bloated that even a tight loop is unlikely to be fewer than 8 uops anyway, so the 32-byte-boundary problem probably doesn't hurt much.  But if you manage to avoid store/reload latency bottlenecks by using `register` on local vars (yes this does something *in debug builds only*, otherwise it's meaningless<sup>1</sup>), the front-end bottleneck of getting all those inefficient instructions through the pipeline could well be impacted on a Skylake CPU if an inner loop ends up tripping over the JCC erratum due to where a conditional branch inside or at the bottom of the loop ends up.

**Anyway, as Eric commented, your assignment is likely more about data access pattern, and possibly layout and alignment**.  Presumably involving a smallish loop over some large amounts of memory, since L2 or L3 cache misses are the only thing that would be slow enough to be more of a bottleneck than building with optimization disabled.  Maybe L1d in some cases, if you manage to get a compiler to make non-terrible asm for debug mode, or if load-use *latency* (not just throughput) is part of the critical path.

##### Footnote 2: `-O0` is dumb, but `register int i` can help

See
[C loop optimization help for final assignment (with compiler optimization disabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/c-loop-optimization-help-for-final-assignment-with-compiler-optimization-disabl) re: how silly it is to optimize source code for debug mode, or benchmark that way for normal use-cases.  But also mentions some things that are faster for that case (unlike normal builds) like doing more in a single statement or expression, since the compiler doesn't keep things in registers across statements.

(See also [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point) for details)

Except `register` variables; that obsolete keyword does still does something for unoptimized builds with GCC (but not clang).  It's officially deprecated or even removed in recent C++ versions, but not C as yet.

You definitely want to use `register int i` to let a debug build keep it in a register, and write your C like it was hand-written asm.  For example, using pointer increments instead of `arr[i]` where appropriate, especially for ISAs that don't have an indexed addressing mode.

`register` variables are most important inside your inner loop, and with optimization disabled the compiler probably isn't very smart about deciding which `register` var actually gets a register if it runs out.  (x86-64 has 15 integer regs other than the stack pointer, and a debug build will spend one of them on a frame pointer.)

Especially for variables that *change* inside loops, to avoid store/reload latency bottlenecks, e.g. `for(register int i=1000000 ; --i ; );` probably runs 1 iteration per clock, vs. 5 or 6 without `register` on a modern x86-64 CPU like Skylake.

If using an integer variable as an array index, make it `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` (`#include <stdint.h>`) if possible, so the compiler doesn't have to redo sign-extension from 32-bit `int` to 64-bit pointer width for use in addressing modes.

(Unless you're compiling for AArch64, which has addressing modes that take a 64-bit register and a 32-bit register, doing sign or zero extension and ignoring high garbage in the narrow integer reg.  Exactly because this is something compilers can't always optimize away.  Although often they can thanks to signed-integer overflow being Undefined Behaviour [allowing the compiler to widen an integer loop variable](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) or convert to a pointer increment.)

Also loosely related: [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-program-for-the-pipeline-in-intel-sandybridge-family-cpus) has a section on intentionally making things slow via cache effects, so do the opposite of that.  Might not be very applicable, IDK what your problem is like.

Comment: Thanks for your titanic effort! I had to read a few thing twice to fully understand them and a couple fall outside of my knowledge but I have to say that this really helped me. Generally speaking, allowed me to grasp the concept I asked for and which had no idea whatsoever when I posted the question. Since I haven't found much about this specific topic in my google searches, your reply sure will help another people too.